# How to make a flex-grow element take up the space of a hidden flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hidden

I want the entire window divided into two or three areas - depending on the state of a checkbox. If the box is not checked I want the second area to be hidden while I want the first area to grow into this additional window space.

The way I set it up for larger screens (>640px) works perfectly fine:
[checked box large screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWa4r.png) and [unchecked box lange screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYC1E.png)

For smaller screens, however, I run into trouble. Here the second area is placed in between area 1 and 3:
[checked box small screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV0HE.png)

But once I uncheck the box, area 1 remains the same and does not grow into the space of the hidden area 2. Instead area 3 moves up and centers itself in the now available space (grey background):
[unchecked box small screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWiDz.png)

I think I know why this happens but have not been able to come up with a solution yet.

As I used `flex-direction: column` for the wrapper the `flex-grow:1` only works horizontally for the children.
Therefore I at first tried to use `flex-direction: row` but that put the elements next to each other horizontally. Even if I tried to use `flex-wrap:wrap` while restricting the wrapper to the viewport width.

The grey space above and below area 3 seems to be the result of the `height:20%` of the hidden area 2. While I thought that using `display:none` would completely stop this height from being considered this seemed not to be the case.
Therefore I secondly tried to use Javascript to change the `height:20%` of the hidden area 2 to 0% only if the box is unchecked and the screen-size is below the threshhold. But in the dev tools it looked like `document.getElementById("hint").style.height="0%"` did not change anything at all. But even if it did it seems like setting the height to 0% directly in the css wont solve my issue as the grey wrapper area still remains.

Here is my attemot of a reproducible example  but I am not sure if it is minimal and of any help:

```js
function visCheck (){
if (document.getElementById("hint").style.display=="block"){ document.getElementById("hint").style.display="none";
}
else if (document.getElementById("hint").style.display=="none"){
document.getElementById("hint").style.display="block";
}
else{   document.getElementById("hint").style.display="block";
}
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
main{
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.maingrid-wrapper{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.maingrid-content{
/*   border: red solid; */
}
.image{
    flex:2 1 60%;
    flex-grow:2;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.sidehint{
    background-color: lightgreen;
    flex:1 1 40%;
    height: 90%;
}

.footer-wrapper{
    background-color: lightpink;
    height:10%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

@media all and (max-width: 640px){
    .maingrid-wrapper{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    .maingrid-content{
/*         border: red solid; */
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .image{
      height: 70%;
        flex:1 1 100%;
        flex-grow: 2;
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
    .sidehint{
        height: 20%;
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
    
    .footer-wrapper{
        height:10%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        background-color: lightpink;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="maingrid-wrapper">
      <div class="image maingrid-content">A</div>
      <div class="sidehint maingrid-content"
           id="hint" style="display:none">B</div>
      <div class="footer-wrapper 
                  maingrid-content">
        <input class="bulb-input" id="hint-toggle"
               type="checkbox"
               onchange="visCheck()">C</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Please put a runnable snippet direct into your question. This is so it is useful for future readers should the external site be deleted or corrected. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Check that it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I hadn't seen how I could insert the code snippet here but added it just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your CSS, which was bloated with redundancy, default values, and extraneous declarations.

Your CSS would benefit from a "mobile first" approach where media queries are used to add styling as the viewport widens, instead of using media queries to overwrite the declarations for narrower viewports.

```js
function visCheck() {

  if (document.getElementById("hint").style.display=="block") {
    document.getElementById("hint").style.display="none";
  }
  else if (document.getElementById("hint").style.display=="none") {
    document.getElementById("hint").style.display="block";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("hint").style.display="block";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  }
  
main{
  height: 100%;
  }

.maingrid-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  }

.maingrid-content{
  /* border: red solid; */
  }

.image{
  flex: 2;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  }

.sidehint{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  }

.footer-wrapper{
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  }

@media all and (max-width: 640px){

  .maingrid-wrapper{
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="maingrid-wrapper">
      <div class="image maingrid-content">A</div>
      <div class="sidehint maingrid-content" id="hint" style="display:none">B</div>
      <div class="footer-wrapper maingrid-content">
        <input class="bulb-input" id="hint-toggle" type="checkbox" onchange="visCheck()">C</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. You are absolutely right. I just started teaching myself css and guess I should definately look into inhertiance of elements next.
Why would you recommend a "mobile-first" approach in this case though? The way you did it it seems like the media queries did not seem excessive.

Comment: @j.heindel Looking back, I assume that I must have written "Your CSS would benefit from a 'mobile first' approach" before I finalized my answer. Looking at it now, the statement doesn't really make sense. Taking a closer look to compare the CSS, I see that I changed your media query declaration from `flex-direction: row` to `flex-direction: column`. "Mobile first" typically takes advantage of the cascade and avoids having to overwrite wide-screen declarations with default values. This optimizes/reduces CSS and improves rendering time.

Comment: Great - I will take that to heart in the future. Thanks a lot!